# WP Total Cache rewrite rules for IIS

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

Does anyone know how to implement the .htaccess rewrite rules from WP Total Cache to work in web.config IIS files?

I am getting my feet wet in the horrid world of MS and can't seem to get the page cache, minify permalinks and browser cache rules to work.

Running IIS 7.5 / Win Server 2008 R2 / PHP 5.3.6 as FastCGI

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert rewrite rules from .htaccess for IIS. WP Total Cache supports IIS by default.

If you have existing rewrite rules in .htacess you can use the IIS Rewrite module to convert those for use in IIS. If these are just standard Pretty Permalinks rules then the latest versions of Wordpress come already with a web.config file which is the IIS equivalent.

Hope this helps.
Mark

Comment: Is WP Total Cache another plugin as W3 Total Cache?